# C# simultaneous endpoint requests return same response

Tags: c#, .net

I have a controller endpoint, which logs in the user based on the parameters. It works fine, but I have discovered, that if two requests are sent (roughly) at the same time, it will log both users in as the first user, which sent the request. I have managed to replicate the bug, by logging in on a normal tab and an incognito tab and rapidly pressing the login buttons, so "simultaneously" would mean roughly in the same second.

```cs
[Route("Auth")]
[OverrideTokenAuthorization(AllowAnonymousAccess = true)]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] CredentialModel credentials)
{
     if (loginModel == null)
     {
         return BadRequest("...");
     }

     try
     {
        // Legacy stuff
        _service = new ServiceFactory(_iocContainer).GetService(...);

        IHttpActionResult result = Authenticate(credentials);

        Logger.Debug(((OkNegotiatedContentResult<TokenModel>)result).Content.access_token);

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error(ex, "...");
        return InternalServerError();
    }
}
```

I have tried multiple solutions, such as using wrapping the code inside the `try` block with `lock`, using `SemaphoreSlim`, using `Mutex` but none work. What are my options?

My `lock` method (which did not work):

```cs
private static readonly object _lockObject = new object();

...
try
{
    lock (_lockObject) 
    {
        // Legacy stuff
        _service = new ServiceFactory(_iocContainer).GetService(...);

        IHttpActionResult result = Authenticate(credentials);

        Logger.Debug(((OkNegotiatedContentResult<TokenModel>)result).Content.access_token);

        return result;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.Error(ex, "...");
    return InternalServerError();
}
...
```

My `SemaphoreSlim` method (which did not work):

```cs
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

_semaphore.Wait();
...
try
{
    // Legacy stuff
    _service = new ServiceFactory(_iocContainer).GetService(...);

    IHttpActionResult result = Authenticate(credentials);

    Logger.Debug(((OkNegotiatedContentResult<TokenModel>)result).Content.access_token);

    _semaphore.Release();

    return result;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.Error(ex, "...");
    return InternalServerError();
}
...
```

The `Authenticate` method creates a new service instance from an external .dll file (legacy stuff) and then writes into the database.

What else can I try to fix the simultaneous login error?

Comment: This sounds like a scoping issue in your `Authenticate` method. Ideally, you would inject a service, having been registered as scoped, and use it there. As we can see that you are instantiating a `new ServiceFactory()` in the `Post` I suspect DI isn't being used everywhere it should.

Comment: There's really not enough info here for us to do anything. For example, what is inside the `Authenticate` method? How does the DI actually work here? What are you creating the `_service` object multiple times since it looks like a class level variable? etc.

Comment: @Philippe @DavidG yes, DI isn't used correctly here, as I said, it's legacy stuff. There's multiple authentication methods (windows AD, normal, etc.), and each uses a different service, which is from a separate dll file. A different service gets instantiated in each separate authentication type endpoint and is then used in a common `Authenticate` method.

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, it looks more like a caching issue than a concurrency one.

The client might be sending the wrong credentials or the Authenticate() method might cache the previous ones somehow.

Try to log the request to see if the client sends different credentials. Use an action filter for this or, if you use OWIN, add a middleware that just logs the request and invokes the next one.

If this is not the problem, create two CredentialModel objects with different credentials and invoke Authenticate() twice in a row:

```
IHttpActionResult result1 = Authenticate(new CredentialModel() { Username = "user1" });
IHttpActionResult result2 = Authenticate(new CredentialModel() { Username = "user2" });
// Check that the results are valid.
```

Comment: I have tried debugging, and each calls gets the appropriate credentials, but it gets mixed somewhere in the authentication. I have also meddled with caching, and tried putting
`[OutputCache(Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]` on the endpoint